# I am stuck in creating the following code in gamelab code.org

Tags: javascript

Anybody can help me in debugging the code , I created the sprite rover and as I call the forward(10) right(90) left(20)...... the rover sprite should move along with the strokes to create the pattern. Currently the pattern is created on the callbacks of the respective functions, but the rover sprite is at one place. How to make the rover move along with the line as the pattern gets created. Below is the code link.

https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/eRXlDQTgdjo6SqTAtni9xTR3QDtoHAnBY3kx4r50pzw/edit

Comment: add your code here, link did not work

Comment: Please add more context to your questions